# How to install PyPi packages using anaconda conda command

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pypi, conda

When using the Anacoda Python distribution, what is the best way to install a PyPi package that isn't available directly through Anaconda?  For now I'm using:

```
conda pipbuild [pypi_name]
conda install --use-local [package_spec]
```

But I'm unclear if this is the best way and if `conda update --all` will update these packages when updates are made available.  I'm also unclear what the point of binstar is when PyPi already exists.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to do this? Could you please share the detailed step-by-step solution? Thank you

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to build conda packages for PyPI packages, the recommended way is to use `conda skeleton pypi package` and use `conda build package` on the recipe that it creates. To install the package, use `conda install --use-local package` (here and elsewhere, `package` is the name of the PyPI package you wish to install).

You will need to update the recipe each time the package is updated.

You can also use `pip` to install these packages. There are two disadvantages: firstly, these packages won't be managed by conda at all. Secondly, these packages will not work if your default python version is different from the python version you are using in conda.

Comment: Thanks!

Dumb question: what does condo managing the packages get me?  Dependency management mostly?  Automatic updates?

Also, why is the method you described preferable to what I described above?

Comment: conda managing things gets you the benefits of dependency management. It also makes it easier to use that package with conda environments. Updates won't happen "automatically" (in the sense that you do need to type `conda update` for that to happen). As to why it's preferable, `conda skeleton` is much more stable than `conda pipbuild`.

Comment: It doesn't say this in http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html#install-non-conda-packages  it just says `pip install x`.  should those instructions be updated?

Comment: and is there a way to have conda manage binary packages like http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikits.audiolab ?

Comment: `conda convert` can convert Gohlke's packages to conda packages http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/build/conda-convert.html

Comment: Final command to install the package: `conda install --use-local package`

Comment: Note that you may need to run `conda install conda-build` to get the `conda skeleton` command (I'm using miniconda).

Comment: @astabada, the package manager is called "conda" and the packages are called "conda packages". "Anaconda" is a distribution of conda packages, and not the only way to use conda.

Comment: I am having this error `pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out` when I tried doing `conda skeleton pypi package`.

Comment: OP doesn't want to build a conda package. He simply wants to install a package from pypi. Conda is a wrapper around pip, I don't understand why the simple channel cannot be added or something, so the whole installation wouldn't become a split personality between pip and conda...

Answer (score 64):

I will disagree with the accepted response and note that `pip install [some-pypi-package]` is often the best way to install PyPi packages in Conda environments.

While the packages won't be managed by the Conda package manager, they will still be managed by the Anaconda environment. It will download the correct version of the package for the active Python install and update it correctly using the `pip` package manager.

When using Anaconda, you should turn to `conda` before `pip` when you can, but you don't lose any of the replicability benefits of using Anaconda when you use `pip`.

Anaconda recently published a doc that supports this: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment

Comment: One issue to be aware of with this: If a `pip` package requires a different version of a dependency already installed by `conda`, `pip` will replace the installed package, and `conda` won't realize its package has been removed. For a one-shot, scripted environment setup, this is probably fine. For an environment that you install into by hand over time, you will likely end up confused after a while.

Comment: One way to mitigate the issue I mentioned above: save the output of `pip freeze` to `constraints.txt` and then install with `pip` using `pip install -c constraints.txt <package>`. This will prevent `pip` from removing `conda` packages. It will also pin `pip` packages. The `pip` packages could be filtered out of `constraints.txt` by looking at the output of `conda list` for the items marked as `<pip>`.

Comment: For things like Django, I’ll set up a virtual environment using Anaconda then do installations purely through pip for reasons mentioned above. Pure conda works best for getting a scientific computing stack together that uses conda channels.

Answer (score 36):

Since [version 4.6.0](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/), Conda has improved its interoperability with pip:

> Conda and pip have historically had difficulties getting along. Pip
> hasn’t respected Conda’s environment constraints, while Conda has been
> all too happy to clobber pip-installed software. It’s a mess. Conda
> 4.6.0 adds preview support for better interoperability. With this interoperability, Conda can use pip-installed packages to satisfy
> dependencies, and can even remove pip-installed software cleanly and
> replace them with Conda packages when appropriate. There’s still room
> for improvement before pip and Conda are hunky-dory BFFs, but we hope
> this is a good start. This feature is disabled by default right now
> because it can significantly impact Conda’s performance. If you’d like
> to try it, you can set this condarc setting:

```
conda config --set pip_interop_enabled True
```

So, the way to get PyPI packages into conda (at the time of writing this) seems to be:

```
pip install <package>
```

If you want conda to replace the PyPI packages with its own (where possible), just run:

```
conda update --all
```

Given that the above setting is made. Conda marks its own channels as higher priority than pip, thus packages will be replaced.

---

There is a caveat (thanks @alfalfasprout): Since conda did not install the pypi packages they are not included in `conda export --from-history`. You'd have to get the list (from conda or pip) and install these packages separately via pip, like you did originally. Thus, for people using the conda history functionality, there is at least a second step needed.

Comment: CondaValueError: Key 'pip_interop_enabled' is not a known primitive parameter.

Comment: What's your conda version? You can check via `conda --version`. I would presume your version is simply older than 4.6.0...

Comment: There are limitations on pip interop though. Conda cannot install pypi packages using the `conda install` command and so packages installed via pypi won't be available when doing a `conda export --from-history`.

Comment: True, you have to install those via pip. Just like you did originally. I'll add this as a caveat to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: First, this is still an experimental option with pitfalls (e.g., see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75476322/570918)). Second, it is unclear how this suggestion helps with *installing* from PyPI - that is already possible with `pip`. Rather, the interoperability option is about letting Conda use PyPI packages *in place of* equally named Conda ones. The premise of OP is that there is no Conda package. Moreover, this option does not enable Conda to search PyPI.

Comment: @merv Not sure I get your comment. Yes, this is still experimental. Yes, the answer says that the best way to get PyPI packages in conda envs is using pip (with the option enabled). Maybe I should say: My answer was meant in the context of the accepted answer and the currently highest voted answer. Both state disadvantages and enabling the setting somewhat alleviates those. I mostly use PyPI packages this way, if they don't exist in conda at all -- so, I am not sure what you mean with that there has to be an equally named conda package. Lastly, OP does not ask for conda to search PyPI, I think

Comment: PS: Ah, I think I get it now: You mean that conda can only satisfy dependencies with PyPI packages if they are equally named. Fair enough, but also relatively obvious. The fact that conda can, for instance, "remove pip-installed software cleanly" is what I meant with enabling the setting somewhat alleviates the disadvantages stated in the other answers, namely managing the PyPI packages in conda.

Comment: I think your second point about removing PyPI packages cleanly is fair and is where the most value of the option is. Please understand that I cannot retract a downvote unless the answer itself is adjusted, for instance, to clarify when exactly it would be appropriate for a user to enable this option. Re: "*relatively obvious*" package naming - it's not though. Users are frequently surprised to find that PyPI package names don't always correspond to Conda package names (e.g., `wget`/`python-wget` comes up often).

Comment: It's certainly not obvious why the names are different. It's "relatively obvious" that it cannot work if they differ (how could the solver possibly know it's the same?).