# Locate where conda placed a python package I installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, miniconda

A `python` newbie question:

On an `Ubuntu` system, I installed a `python` package using `sudo pip install`. (The package is called `hlmm`)

I'm using the `miniconda3` environment and the only `environment variable` specified in my `.bashrc` is:

```
export PATH="/home/<my_username>/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Now I want to run a test script from the package I installed, which is located under a `tests` folder relative to where that package was installed.

I used `pip list | xargs -exec pip show` to look for the location of that package but it doesn't show up.

I also tried in `python` to import the package, using:

```
import hlmm
```

And I'm getting:

```
>>> import hlmm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hlmm'
```

If I redo `sudo pip install hlmm` I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: hlmm in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: pysnptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.19.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pysnptools->hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.19.0->pysnptools->hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas>=0.19.0->pysnptools->hlmm)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas>=0.19.0->pysnptools->hlmm)
```

And, I do see the `hlmm` folder under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but cannot find that `tests` folder:

```
ls -1 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hlmm
__init__.py
__init__.pyc
hetlm.py
hetlm.pyc
hetlmm.py
hetlmm.pyc
```

How do I find its location? And, is the package really successfully installed despite the `import hlmm` error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda site-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003994/anaconda-site-packages)

Comment: This link does not solve my problem. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: An issue can be that you are not searching the miniconda environment, but a pre-installed `python2.7` version. If, in the interpreter that shows `no module named hlmm` you type `import sys
print(sys.version)` do you get `2.7`? Have you activated the miniconda environment that you install `hlmm` into?

Comment: Thanks @Mason Caiby. Yes, I activated my `miniconda` environment (`source activate /home/<my_username>/miniconda3`) before trying to import the package. `print(sys.version)` returns: `3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) [GCC 7.2.0]`

Comment: is `hlmm` included in the packages shown with `conda list` after activating your package?

Comment: No, it doesn't show up. Is it possible that the `sudo pip install hlmm` I ran to install it (after activating my `miniconda` environment) is at fault and I should have installed it differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was getting too long to be a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer.

Yeah, it sounds like `pip` installed it from your python 2.7 version. You should read this post: [How to install PyPi packages using anacaonda conda command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286624/how-to-install-pypi-packages-using-anacaonda-conda-command) and this article: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/ to decide how you want to proceed. I generally use `conda` when possible, and `pip` if conda doesn't have a build. You might want to run `pip uninstall hlmm` then activate your conda env and use `pip3 install hlmm`. But, I think you should decide the best way to manage your environments after doing research.

Comment: This might not solve your problem, using conda after you have installed things with python (or even sometimes when you have 2 python versions installed) can be a huge pain. Let me know if it works or not.