# How to install a package on my jupyter notebook that is only available on pip and not in conda?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, conda, asammdf

I am trying to install a package using pip on my cluster which is behind my company's proxy server. My company has a full clone for all the conda packages. Any request to install any packages goes to my company's conda packages cloud from where we install the packages. So we cannot download any pip packages.

```
!pip3 install asammdf
```

This gives me :

```
Collecting asammdf
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6d7d32b70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/asammdf/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6d7d32e48>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/asammdf/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6d7d32d30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/asammdf/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6d7d32470>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/asammdf/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe6d7d32128>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/asammdf/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asammdf (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for asammdf
```

I need to install this `asammdf` package on my cluster, is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Name or service not known` means your pip or network config is bad. Your command is fine

Comment: Why can't you use `!conda install`, though?

Comment: because that package is not available in conda

Comment: @cricket_007 I am unable to install anything using pip, however conda works fine but since few packages are specific to pip

Comment: Why can't you use conda again? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57522799/2308683

Comment: pip just won't work, is there any solution using conda?

Comment: conda forge can be used, but will it work for all the packages

Comment: You will have to check that yourself for the packages that you want to install. What kind of network are you on? Are you in a company/school or similar that might require a proxy setting of some sort?

Comment: yes its my company's proxy

Comment: 1) You need to show us how your proxy is configured. 2) conda documentation suggests it works with pip packages https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html 3) sure, it doesn't work for all. How about you download the packages manually from your company mirror, then install files locally?

Comment: my company has cloned only the packages specific to conda

Answer (score 0):

Asammdf is available in conda forge. Is this not cloned by your internal server?

Comment: please read the comments, I have stated that  eventually I had to download it from the conda forge. But what about other packages that is specific to pip

Comment: for pip to work you need to give it the proxy: ``pip install --proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy_url> asammdf``