# Conda Skeleton throws FileNotFoundError at end

Tags: python, conda, pypi, miniconda, python-packaging

I've got a fresh miniconda environment and I'm trying to follow the recipe in SO post [How to install PyPi packages using anaconda conda command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286624/how-to-install-pypi-packages-using-anaconda-conda-command) to create a conda package for pypi module o365.  I'm in win10 but getting FileNotFoundError at the end.

Any advice?

```
(mytest) C:\conda skeleton pypi o365
Warning, the following versions were found for o365
0.5
0.5.2
0.6
0.6.1
0.6.2
0.6.3
0.6.4
0.6.5
0.6.9
0.7
0.9
0.9.1
0.9.2
0.9.3
0.9.4
0.9.5
0.9.6
0.9.7
0.9.8
0.9.9
0.9.10
0.9.11
0.9.12
0.9.13
0.9.14
0.9.15
0.9.16
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.0.3
1.0.4
1.0.5
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.2
1.1.3
1.1.4
1.1.5
1.1.6
1.1.7
1.1.8
1.1.9
1.1.10
2.0.0
2.0.1
2.0.2
2.0.3
2.0.4
2.0.5
2.0.6
2.0.7
Using 2.0.7
Use --version to specify a different version.
Using url https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/1c/2d5f079fdcf0b082654afaf17866de515580bbff1660bb905f6bddc1cd54/O365-2.0.7.tar.gz (141 KB) for o365.
Downloading o365
PyPI URL:  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/1c/2d5f079fdcf0b082654afaf17866de515580bbff1660bb905f6bddc1cd54/O365-2.0.7.tar.gz
Using cached download
Unpacking o365...
done
working in C:\Users\MARK~1.SIS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpt7_7oo0hconda_skeleton_O365-2.0.7.tar.gz
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\conda-bld\skeleton_1585098002351\_h_env


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2020.1.1-0
    certifi:         2019.11.28-py37_1
    openssl:         1.1.1e-he774522_0
    pip:             20.0.2-py37_1
    python:          3.7.7-h60c2a47_0_cpython
    pyyaml:          5.3.1-py37he774522_0
    setuptools:      46.1.1-py37_0
    sqlite:          3.31.1-he774522_0
    vc:              14.1-h0510ff6_4
    vs2015_runtime:  14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1
    wheel:           0.34.2-py37_0
    wincertstore:    0.2-py37_0
    yaml:            0.1.7-hc54c509_2

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Applying patch: 'C:\\Users\\MARK~1.SIS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpt7_7oo0hconda_skeleton_O365-2.0.7.tar.gz\\pypi-distutils.patch'
Trying to apply patch as-is
INFO:conda_build.source:Trying to apply patch as-is
INFO conda_build.source:apply_patch(598): Trying to apply patch as-is

Leaving build/test directories:
  Work:
 C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\conda-bld\skeleton_1585098002351\work
  Test:
 C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\conda-bld\skeleton_1585098002351\test_tmp
Leaving build/test environments:
  Test:
source activate  C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\conda-bld\skeleton_1585098002351\_test_env
  Build:
source activate  C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\conda-bld\skeleton_1585098002351\_build_env


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\Scripts\conda-skeleton-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_skeleton.py", line 65, in main
    return execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_skeleton.py", line 61, in execute
    version=args.version, config=config)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 290, in skeletonize
    recursive=recursive, config=config, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\skeletons\pypi.py", line 319, in skeletonize
    setup_options=setup_options)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\skeletons\pypi.py", line 726, in get_package_metadata
    config=config)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\skeletons\pypi.py", line 1127, in get_pkginfo
    setup_options=setup_options)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\skeletons\pypi.py", line 1189, in run_setuppy
    apply_patch(join(stdlib_dir, 'distutils'), patch, config=config)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\source.py", line 599, in apply_patch
    check_call_env([patch] + patch_args, cwd=src_dir, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\utils.py", line 404, in check_call_env
    return _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ('call', *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\site-packages\conda_build\utils.py", line 395, in _func_defaulting_env_to_os_environ
    subprocess.check_call(_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\subprocess.py", line 358, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Miniconda\envs\mytest\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```