# How to include pip-only package when building conda package by using conda-build?

Tags: python, conda, pypi, conda-build

I would like to build a Conda package for my project. However, there is one package that is on pip-only (not uploaded to Conda channel). How to include pip only package when using conda-build command?

I tried using Conda skeleton to build a package from PyPI URL but it doesn't work because the file on PyPI site is a .whl file instead of a tar.gz file like in the conda skeleton tutorial. How should I solve this problem?

This is the error I got for when running the conda build.

```
conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform osx-64: {'plaidml'}
```

and for skeleton build for plaidml package by using `conda skeleton pypi plaidml-keras`

```
Error: No source urls found for plaidml-keras
```

Is there a good practice of how to include the pip only package when building conda package?

Comment: AFAIK, you have the right idea: try to convert the dependency to a Conda package. Unfortunately, that package looks like a rather involved build - unlikely `skeleton` will do the job. Not sure any generic advice here is going to help; instead, I'd get in touch with the developers and see if they'd support you developing a Conda version.

Comment: @merv Thank you for the comment. I will try to get in touch with the developer.

Comment: This procedure could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29304731/8288189

Answer (score 2):

I looks around in the conda-build docs, and it looks like you can build a conda package using a wheel as a dependency. From the [conda-build user guide docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/wheel-files.html):

> To build a conda package from a wheel file, install the .whl file in
> the conda recipe's bld.bat or build.sh file.
>
> You may download the .whl file in the source section of the conda
> recipe's meta.yaml file.
>
> You may instead put the URL directly in the pip install command.
>
> EXAMPLE: The conda recipe for TensorFlow has a pip install command in
> build.sh with the URL of a .whl file. The meta.yaml file does not
> download or list the .whl file.
>
> Note
>
> It is important to pip install only the one desired package. Whenever
> possible, install dependencies with conda and not pip.
>
> We strongly recommend using the --no-deps option in the pip install
> command.
>
> If you run pip install without the --no-deps option, pip will often
> install dependencies in your conda recipe and those dependencies will
> become part of your package. This wastes space in the package and
> increases the risk of file overlap, file clobbering, and broken
> packages.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning from the docs also: "The best way is to obtain the source code for the software and build a conda package from the source and not from a wheel. This helps ensure that the new package uses other conda packages to satisfy its dependencies.

The second best way is to build a conda package from the wheel file. This tells conda more about the files present than a pip install. It is also less likely than a pip install to cause errors by overwriting (or "clobbering") files. Building a conda package from the wheel file also has the advantage that any clobbering is more ..."