# Importing traci gives "package not found" error

Tags: python, import, anaconda, sumo

I am running a simulation code written in python and simulator is sumo. I am using anaconda in ubuntu 20.04. To run a program I need to import traci and I am trying to install but it shows that package not found.

I have created new environment and tried "conda install -c conda-forge traci". But it shows error like this:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- traci

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no conda package of traci, you can still use `pip install traci` even in an anaconda environment. Please beware of the caveats mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45361152/5731587